# Custom variable in visitor-level or session-level?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics in my Android application.

I want to slice an event by version code, so I thought to add a custom variable with the version code inside.

My question is what level should I set the variable? visitor or session?

In the beginning, I thought to add it as a visitor level custom variable. 
But if a user will upgrade my application, I want that old events will still attached to the old version code.
If I'll change the variable (as visitor level), all old events are going to be with the new value?